# Nonsingularity of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

Let $X=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
C & 0
\end{array}\right)$
  and:

If  $X$ is non-singular, is $A$ non-singular when $B$ is full column rank and $C$ is full row rank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$